# How can i start SplashScreen activity when ANR dialog appears?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

i want to start splash screen activity or Main Activity immediately when ANR dialog appears. i used ANRWatchDog library previously but that is also not working correctly.how can i do this? any useful library ?or any alternative ?

Comment: Fix your ANR that might be the best solution.

Comment: fix ANR https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Answer (score 0):

ANR is triggered by the system and there is no way of catching that. Only solution to this is fix ANR. Do not let ANR be triggered by the system. ANR is triggered  if an application blocks on some I/O operation (frequently a network access) on the UI thread. To overcome this sitaution,  you should not perform the work on the UI thread but instead create a worker thread and do most of the work there.